# UML: Derived class constructor runs abstract method - how to mark it

Tags: uml

Im UML newbie:)

I have abstract class X with methods A and method B (both with implementation). I have class Y with derives from class X.

I want to mark on UML diagram, that class Y constructor must run  X.methodA, and Y.method3 must run X.methodB. How to put it on UML diagram?

Comment: I guess you mean that they must implement certain methods?

Comment: yes, contructor of derived  must run/call call X.methodA() (X is base class). How to mark it on UML schema? Or if this is needed on UML schema?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to define in behavioral diagram. UML defines operation (behavioral feature) and behavior. Behavior can be connected to operation as a method. You should define owned behavior in class X, and then call it in behavioral diagram defined in class Y. I recommend you to read UML Superstructure document chapter Common Behavior.  [UML Web](http://www.uml.org)